# How to generate dynamic path in dataset during the output method

Tags: apache-flink

Is there a way to create a dynamic DataSink output path in Flink?

DataSet has data type as `Tuple2<String, String>`

When we tried using stream I had a way to generate dynamic bath using custom Bucketer like below

```
@Override
    public Path getBucketPath(Clock clock, Path basePath, Tuple2<String, String> element) {
        return new Path(basePath + "/schema=" + element.f0.toLowerCase().trim() + "/");
    }
```

I would like to know is there a similar way to handle in DataSet for generating the custom path.

Answer (score 0):

I poked around a bit, and didn't find anything similar for batch processing. Which means I think you'd have to create your own `OutputFormat` class that wraps a regular `FileOutputFormat` and does bucketing, using the same Bucketer interface.